# Google Sheets Area Graph(s)

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-arrayformula, google-sheets-charts, google-sheets-dates

I need (want) to create a Google Sheets Area Graph (Chart).

The Graph/Chart will represent "Date"s.
I need the Xaxis to be the dates (as days) between these start and end dates:
01/27/2020, 4/25/2020 (these dates are in separate Cells of the same row in my Sheet.)

I don't want to create by hand 90 rows of days/dates between 01/27/2020 and 4/25/2020 to use as the Xaxis.
I want a "for" loop to create those 90 dates, then the Area Graph/Chart to use the result as the Xaxis.

The Yaxis will be a value like '10', and the same '10' for each date, and a color like 'brown' or 'yellow'. 
In the end, the chart will be a 'brown' box, 90 units wide Xaxis, 10 tall Yaxis, with the 90 day dates as the Xaxis legend.

It is possible that I will then use the concept to also create several contiguous Areas adding up to the same end point. For example: The main brown box, 90 days wide, then a shorter (not as tall as '10') yellow or blue box starting at 03/04/2020 and ending at 03/31/2020. etc.

Since "Area" is the same concept as "Line" except with the color fill to the baseline, I'm thinking "Area" for no other reason but appearance.

I do not know where and how to correctly put such a "for loop".
Some references I have read are so old that Google Sheets no longer has such Options.

Do I create the 90 days dates with a for loop in a new Cell in that row as the start/end dates, and '10' as the Yaxis value is another new Cell? Then Insert the Chart based on those 2 Cells??

I have attempted to do this with PHP and JpGraph, and have been moderately successful, but Google Sheets is the data source, and it seems to me I should keep things in one drawer.

I am anxious for pointers to focus on Sheets/Java functions, and where they need to be placed! I have done a few things with Sheets. but I have done extensive Google Maps with javascript "for loops" that I have copy/paste'd/edited from code snippets, etc, but in a PHP page.
Time to learn new things - even though these things have been around 15 years!

Something similar that I did in PHP/JpGraph:
[image]